# Opa: How to Interact With the Database Without Blocking the UI

Tags: opa

### The Setup

I have a (rather standard) form that allows a user to create an account by entering a username and password. When the `#username` field loses focus, the database is queried to see if the supplied username is available.

### The Problem

Everything works as expected, but the user interface is blocked from when the `onblur` event of `#username` is triggered until the database returns a value. How can check the database in an asyncronous and non-blocking fashion?

Here's my code (I've pulled most of this code out of example Opa projects):

#### Types

```
@abstract type User.ref = string

type User.t = 
  { username : string
  ; passwd : string
  }

type User.map('a) = ordered_map(User.ref, 'a, String.order)
```

#### Database

```
db /user : User.map(User.t)
```

#### Form

```
<form>
  <input id=#username type="text" onblur={_ -> username_available() } placeholder="username" />
  <input id=#password type="password" placeholder="password" />
</form>
```

#### Actions

```
username_available() : void =
  user = Dom.get_value(#username)
  match (get_user(user)) with
  | { none } -> Log.notice("username available:", "YES")
  | { some = _ } -> Log.notice("username available:", "NO")

get_user(username : string) : option(User.t) =
  match ?/user[username] with
  | { none } -> Option.none
  | { ~some } -> Option.some(some)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question. The answer is quite simple: add `@async` directive before your `username_available` function. It is still somewhat experimental and therefore not documented. Any feedback welcome!

PS. A detail, but if you include simple code, personally I'd rather see a complete listing in one go (easier to copy&paste&run); possibly with comments in place of headers.

Comment: This is working _perfectly_ for me. Thanks. :)

I pulled this out of a rather cumbersome module; I was unsure how to make the question clear. I'll make sure my next examples are compile-ready.